# refname is ambiguous and pull failing

Tags: git, branch

I ran the following command as I wanted to move my production branch back without having to checkout first:

```
git branch -f production HEAD~1
```

I am now getting the following warning when I checkout production:

```
warning: refname 'production' is ambiguous.
```

I then run:

```
git pull
```

And I receive the following error:

```
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded production to 7463e01c536ad52746b8879ef3d70ffd5a8db31e.
error: Ref refs/heads/production is at 252038dfa22caba8a816a68dcb005c625e44c51f but expected ae5b621609c1b5b430e3d30711157298f842942a
fatal: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/heads/production'
Could not move back to refs/heads/production
```

I can pull on other branches though. How can I fix this?

**Further Info**

`git tag` doesn't return any output. I previously had a production repository, but I've now renamed it to live

```
> ~/repo (chris-membership-fees)$ git show-ref | grep production
88e0c37c9ae4ff6967ddd027b62b62fa2c0ac272 refs/heads/production
9d739cff44a898f0c68da33fb22a230985e479ce refs/remotes/backup/production

~/repo (chris-membership-fees)$ git branch -a | grep production
  production
  remotes/backup/production
```

**Log**

I tagged the first revision as a and the second as b (note that the revision numbers have changed as production is now different). This is the log, simplified by decoration

```
* commit 7463e01c536ad52746b8879ef3d70ffd5a8db31e (**tag: a**, backup/live-master, production, live-master)
| 
| Date:   Wed Dec 28 11:47:49 2011 +1100
| 
|     Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/joseph-quick-fix'
|  
* commit f35f0259c4e36d46dd1df71b3293bef6105cef98 (origin/hotfix-googleplusdirectconnect)
| 
| Date:   Fri Dec 23 12:25:27 2011 +1100
| 
|     Add google plus link tag to home page for direct connect
|    
*   commit 8b3a30ef2909439ac18b65ebbb316eb0cdd2d61c
|\  Merge: f696f3e 88e0c37
| | 
| | Date:   Wed Dec 21 14:28:45 2011 +1100
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'master' into chris-hotfix
| |   
* | commit f696f3e2b8f4a19ec2b2c2a3638c68e7a52836e3 (origin/chris-hotfix, backup/chris-hotfix, chris-hotfix)
| | 
| | Date:   Wed Dec 21 11:56:10 2011 +1100
| | 
| |     Fixed buyer price info
| |     
| *   commit 88e0c37c9ae4ff6967ddd027b62b62fa2c0ac272
| |\  Merge: c9655da ae5b621
| |/  
|/|   Date:   Wed Dec 21 11:53:36 2011 +1100
| |   
| |       Merge branch 'master' of git.freelancer.com:production into production
| |   
* | commit ae5b621609c1b5b430e3d30711157298f842942a (HEAD, **tag: b**)
| | 
| | Date:   Wed Dec 21 10:51:47 2011 +1100
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'master' of git.freelancer.com:production
| |   
| * commit c9655da9c1627ab53720ae818affdd1e6f14119f (origin/game-shadow2)
| | 
| | Date:   Tue Dec 20 18:41:57 2011 -0500
| | 
| |     * Removed debugging code
| |     
| *   commit ca88d33538bd3b99ea7c186b5b531e611847989d
| |\  Merge: 99e983a c397a8b
| |/  
|/|   Date:   Tue Dec 20 17:25:24 2011 -0500
| |   
| |       Merge remote-tracking branch 'production/master' into shadow2
```

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -a`?

Comment: You can also use `git show-ref` to show all refs un-abbreviated.

Comment: Which version of git are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Johannes Sixt on the Git [mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/187853).

> The most likely reason is that you have a ref 'production' directly in
>   the .git directory. Perhaps you or one of your scripts created it
>   accidentally using 'git update-ref production ae5b621', i.e., without
>   giving the full ref path name

It wasn't actually in the .git root directory, but I had an empty production folder in branches.

Comment: I accidentally created a file called 'master' using git-update-ref and this caused the same problem. The simple fix was to remove the .git/master file. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 6):

```
> ~/repo (chris-membership-fees)$ git show-ref | grep production
88e0c37c9ae4ff6967ddd027b62b62fa2c0ac272 refs/heads/production
9d739cff44a898f0c68da33fb22a230985e479ce refs/remotes/backup/production
88e0c37c9ae4ff6967ddd027b62b62fa2c0ac272 refs/remotes/production/master
```

`refs/heads/production` is ambiguos due to `refs/remotes/production`. Resolution is generic and independent of the reference-type prefix, thus branches, tags, remotes and even custom ref names must not collide.

Comment: I renamed production to live and so only the first two results now appear, but I am still seeing the clash

Comment: do you mean `error: Ref refs/heads/live is at 252038dfa22caba8a816a68dcb005c625e44c51f but expected ae5b621609c1b5b430e3d30711157298f842942al`, or `warning: refname 'live' is ambiguous.`?

Comment: I still have both issues. One when I checkout, the other when I pull. I am now using livemaster as my local branch without issues, but I am still curious as to what the issue is

Comment: could you show us the simplified tree? it doesn't make much sense to me right now :S.

Comment: With simplified, I mean a tree containing only the relevant items. BTW, to avoid any further confusion, I was talking about history, not files. The easiest way to do it is to tag both commits mentioned by the error and run `git log --all --simplify-by-decoration`.

Comment: Or better: `git log --graph --simplify-by-decoration --decorate=full --all`. That will make it pretty explicit, I guess...

Comment: @Casebash: 1) You're on a detached head, that's why the pull error. That's because you've moved the branch you were on (and we all thought you were on other branch). So basically you're on that branch but on a different "point in time".

Comment: @Casebash: now you should either checkout to another branch and go back to production or do a `git reset`. That will solve your problem :).

Comment: Not quite the answer, but I awarded you the bounty anyway for effort

Comment: Thanks. Never thought about the possibility of an empty (thus sort-of invisible) directory in the refs. It's weird that you got it...

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to remove the warning:

```
git config --global core.warnambiguousrefs false
```

The warning is coming because you have a branch named production and also a remote named production. It will be ideal to rename either of the two to something else.

Comment: I don't think this quite makes sense, though - as I read the [git rev-parse](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions) documentation, it's only if `refs/remotes/production/HEAD` exists that the `production` remote will create ambiguity, and that's not shown in the `git show-ref` output.

Comment: @Mark: You are right. I renamed production to live, but I am still seeing the ambiguity warning

Comment: @manojlds: Thanks, I now have problems pulling when on the production branch as well.